# Is there any way to specify eg (car|cars) in a cucumber step definition?

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

So I have 2 scenarios....one starts out

```
Given I have 1 car
```

The other starts out

```
Given I have 2 cars
```

I'd like them to use the same step definition - ie something like this

```
 Given('I have {int} (car|cars)',
```

I know it's possible to do specify 2 possible values (ie car or cars), but I can't for the life of me remember how.  Does anyone know?  I'm using typescript, protractor, angular, selenium.

Have also tried

```
Given(/^I have {int} (car|cars)$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within cukeExp, the () become optional characters. That is what you want.

So your expression would be

```
Given('I have {int} car(s)')
```

Happy to help - More information can be found here: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/ - Switch to JS code at the top.

Luke - Cucumber contributor.

Comment: Live example: https://testjam.io/?p=zn0Cc1ev33sFLIAk1bz5

Answer (score 2):

Luke's answer is great and is definitely standard practice when cuking.

I would (and do) take a different approach. I would strongly argue that the complexity of even a single expression like the one he uses isn't worth the step duplication. Let me explain and illustrate.

The fundamental idea behind this approach is that the internals of each step definition must be a single call to a helper method. When you do this you no longer need expressions or regex's.

I would prefer and use in my projects

```
module CarStepHelper
  def create_car(amount: 1)
    Lots of stuff to create cars
  end
end
World CarStepHelper

Given 'I have one car' do
  create_car
end

Given 'I have two cars' do
  create_car(amount: 2)
end
```

to

```
Given('I have {int} car(s)')
 lots of stuff to create cars
end
```

because

- the step definitions are simpler (no regex, no cucumber expression
- the stuff to create the cars is slightly simpler (no processing of the regex or expression)
- the helper method supports and encourages a wider range of expression e.g.

```
Given Fred has a car
Given there is a blue car and a red car
```

- the helper method encourages better communication between steps because you can assign its results relative to the step definition e.g.

```
Given Fred has a car
 @freds_car = create_car
end

Given there are two cars
 [@car1, @car2] = create_car(amount: 2)
end
```

Cucumber expressions and cucumbers regex's are very powerful and quite easy to use, but you can Cuke very effectively without ever using them. Step definition efficiency is a myth and often an anti-pattern, if you ensure each step def is just a single call you no longer have to worry about it, and you will avoid the mistake many cukers fall into which is the writing over-complicated step definitions with lots of parameters, regex's and|or expressions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, your step definition should be as below for it to work.

`Given(/^I have "([^"]*)?" (car|cars)*$/, (number, item) => {`

You can still simplify the first regular expression.

Cheers!