# cucumber-js cannot find the step definition when a variable is needed

Tags: javascript, cucumber, bdd, cucumberjs

I have a feature

```
// test.feature
    Feature: Test1

      Scenario: To test variables
         Given When no variable succeed
         When When value blah and value blah3


    // test_steps.js
    const { Before, Given, When, Then } = require('cucumber');
const assert = require('assert');


Given(/^When no variable succeed$/, function () {
    assert.equal(1,1)
  });

When(/^When value {string} and value {string}$/, function (val1, val2) {
    return 'pending';
});
```

what the results are

```
> Scenario: To test variables #
> tests/bdd/features_cucumber/test.feature:3    ✔ Given When no variable
> succeed # tests/bdd/features_cucumber/step_definitions/test_steps.js:5
> ? When When value blah and value blah3
>        Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:
> 
>          When('When value blah and value blah3', function () {
>            // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
>            return 'pending';
>          });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to specify eg (car|cars) in a cucumber step definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60758919/is-there-any-way-to-specify-eg-carcars-in-a-cucumber-step-definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add quotes around the variables in the feature file
`When When value "blah" and value "blah3"`

And you don't need the regular expressing in the step definition.
`When('When value {string} and value {string}', function (val1, val2) {` should do

If you use regular expression in your step definition, then you have to use capturing groups for your values. e.g:
`When(/^When value "([^"]*)" and value "([^"]*)"$/, function (val1, val2) {`